# Cannot read property 'style' of null Sharetribe CMS

Tags: javascript, html, css, content-management-system

I'm using Sharetribe https://rentim.sharetribe.com/ to build a marketplace. The tool is very limited, I don't have access to source code. I can only add scripts. These scripts are injected inside the `<head>` tag. I try to edit it by adding the code below. The code works well until I paste it into the console, but while I add it to the live version there's an Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'style' of null. Can you please help me figure out what the problem is?

```
var allCategories = document.querySelector('a.home-categories-main:first-child.selected');
var filters = document.querySelector('#filters');
filters.style.display = allCategories ? 'block' : 'none';
```

Comment: do you have an element with id=filters? is it loaded yet?

Comment: This element is in the body section, so the script is loaded before this element.

Comment: depends on how contents are loaded. I.e. if  it renders data basing on JS call.

Comment: @Mort any ideas on how to load this script?

Comment: @MikeKaras Ach, I've got you wrong at first. Well, you just need to check if everything is rendered, that should be enough. 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/DOMContentLoaded_event

    `window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', (event) => {
      console.log('DOM fully loaded and parsed');
    });`. just stay advised that it WON'T work if you have dynamic content. That'd be pretty hard to make

Comment: `so the script is loaded before this element` then it may not exist

Comment: @Bravo how to handle this?